# I found two stars which weren't part of the challenges of previous weeks of season 5, what does this mean?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

So I have found two stars which weren't part of previous week's challenges of season 5. That's why I thought it is probably either a part of challenges from week prior to season 5 or from the upcoming weeks because I only paid for a battle pass from season 5. The first you can consult on [this page](https://invictusi.imgur.com/all) but the second I don't recall.

> My question is which of the two assumptions stated above is the right one?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Each week there is a new place on the map where a hidden star can be found if you completed that week. Have you found one of these?

Comment: I've edited my question. And the location is the rocky place between Lazy Links and Pleasant Park.

Comment: IIRC that star is from Week 3 or 4 of the challenges. As @SPYBUG96 said, each week new challenges are released, and one of those is always some form of finding a hidden battle star. There are 10 weeks of challenges in Season 5 so, if you just recently bought it, you will still be able to access all previous weeks.

Comment: Also, to prove the point its from other weeks, Lazy Links didnt exist until season 5, so your question title, saying that its not part of season 5, is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rocky place, as you call it, is the umbrella shaped quarry you can see in the map on the loading screen you received for completing all of the challenges for your first week of season 5. Secret battle stars are given through clues in all the loading screens and you won't see them listed in the challenges menu.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thx for the explanation.